# Android. Нехватка памяти.

Tags: android

Есть сервис (использует START_STICKY), который создает BroadcastReceiver на SCREEN_OFF, SCREEN_ON. (Приложение - Lockscreen). При высокой нагрузке на телефон, сервис отключается и не перезагружается. Как понизить шансы убийства сервиса?

Посидел с DDMS.

1) Включаю приложение - выделено 10мб памяти (на моем телефоне у ЛЮБОГО приложения так, не совсем понимаю, куда столько выделяется), проверил на другом телефоне, там 3мб выделяется.

2) Включаю сервис - особо ничего дополнительно не выделятся, так как ничего большого там нет, только парочку BroadcastReceiver'ов

3) Прослушивается SCREEN_OFF, включается локскрин, тут уже нормальное выделение памяти, Heap Size - 25 mb, если еще и играться с локскрином, Heap Size возрастает до 40-50mb.

4) Отключаем локскрин, выделение 10 - 11 мб (если все очистить), однако Heap Size то не уменьшается... как я понимаю, это увеличивает шансы на убийство процесса...? И с этим ничего не поделать?
Ну ладно убивается, оно ведь потом еще и не включается обратно (START_STICKY не работает)

P.S.
Стоит ли использовать startForeground()?

Comment: > Как понизить шансы убийства сервиса?

представьте, что такое бы существовало. Тогда, скорее всего, все этим пользовались. Но память то не резиновая и имеет свойство заканчиваться. Но Пользователь хочет запускать игры, браузер и идти в соцсети. И мешать ему нельзя. Иначе он выбросит телефон.

Поэтому, так просто понизить шансы нельзя.

Comment: Запускайте сервис с отдельном процессе например.

Comment: Deadkenny, какая разница? 
KoVadim, хорошо, тогда остается проблема в перезапуске сервиса, почему сервис порой не перезапускается?

Comment: @azat  если у него есть какая-то специфическая работа с памятью, то вся память процесса достанется ему.  А сервис запускается с START_STICKY?

Comment: Запускается с START_STICKY, специфической работы с памятью нет. Само приложение особо памяти не ест.